# Looking for a sample doubleclick ad serve logs for BigQuery analysis

Tags: google-bigquery, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I'm building a BigQuery application and am looking for a sample data set from Double Click for Publishers. Specifically, ad serve logs in CSV for a sample period including Clicks, Impressions, and ActiveViews. Has anyone come across a sample along these lines? I've looked through the DCP docs but haven't found anything useable for validation using my customer's sample queries.

Comment: This was a good question, not sure why it was put on hold. We developed a PHP simple app using Faker to generate the schema. It's not too much but I can share what we have.

Comment: I agree with @Pentium10. There is nothing wrong with this question as it pertains to development using DFP <-> BigQuery integration. It's a valid question - I've been there myself. Can a mod please review for reopening.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe someone from the DFP team will correct me, but AFAIK there are no public samples available. We also tried searching for the something similar when we were building our DFP -> BigQuery ingest engine, but we could not find anything at that time.

What we did for initial POC/test:

1. Generate some sample logs using the schemas found [here](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1733128?hl=en). This allowed us to get build the initial codebase for our ETL pipelines.
2. Once we had a rough application based off the sample logs we generated, we then asked our DFP rep to switch on the actual data transfer feeds. Our code needed some minor work, but for the most part it worked.

BTW (shameless plug), I wrote a blog about how we ingest our DFP logs [here](https://shinesolutions.com/2015/02/25/test-driving-google-cloud-dataflow-alpha/) and [here](https://shinesolutions.com/2016/03/30/creating-a-serverless-etl-nirvana-using-google-bigquery/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have sample schema for the files you tested? And does BigQuery also takes care of updates in the data?